# Error at if statement deflection in java program

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm having a bug really really weird with Java here!

I have a `LinkedList` with size three and when I compare it with zero it is evaluated as `True`!
Why for god's sake does this happen!?

The code:

```
    long depth = 0;
    long initial = System.currentTimeMillis();

    OthelloStateNode root = new OthelloStateNode(_state);

    List<OthelloStateNode> children = root.generateChildren();

    System.out.println("SIZE: " + children.size());

    if (children.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
```

The generateChildren() function:

```
     public List<OthelloStateNode> generateChildren() {
            // expand children, if necessary
            if (children == null) {
                children = new LinkedList<>();
                for (OthelloMove move : state.generateMoves()) {
                    OthelloStateNode child = new OthelloStateNode(state.applyMoveCloning(move));
                    child.movement = move;
                    child.parent = this;

                    children.add(child);
                }
            }
            return children;
        }
```

The output of the `println` is "SIZE: 3"! There is no reason for it to be `True`.

Apparently, if I remove the `System.currentTimeMillis()` it works correctly... But it shouldn't be related with the question if 3 is equal to 0 or not, should it?

Does someone there knows something about this?
Here is the code, if you want to download and test if it also happens in your machine: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bxl_AQ6nM3yXVnAzdXg5MFUtVTg/edit

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It returns true, or it returns null? There is no return true here..

Comment: I'm willing to take a bet that this doesn't turn out to be a Java bug.

Comment: Can we see the definition of OthelloStateNode class and generateChildren() method?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I wrote this poorly. The IF statement is evaluated as TRUE, and the function returns NULL at that point.

Comment: Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which can be used to reproduce the problem? From what's currently posted, it looks, highly unlikely.

Comment: `OthelloStateNode` is immense and the only part that really matters is the method `generateChildren()`. `.size()` and `.isEmpty()` are the native methods of the `LinkedList<E>` class.

Comment: Are you very sure you're returning `null` from there and not somewhere else? Can you put a sysout in the `isEmpty()` check?

Comment: *"the only part that really matters"*  Is that your way of saying 'no SSCCE needed'?

Comment: @JeroenVannel: Yes, I am sure. I'm seeing the evaluation of that statement by Java debug (netbeans 7.4).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: no buddy, I already put it in the end of the post. I said that when MohammadS. asked to see the OthelloStateNode class, and considering it is quite big, I thought that put this in this post would be irrational. There is no need to be hostile.

Comment: Works just fine in my machine...in fact, it never gets into the `return null;`

Comment: Ok, this is awkward... Some problem with my debugger, probably?

Comment: @user2429640 just place a breakpoint at the `return null;` line, debug, and when it stops take a look at the contents of `children`. You'll find it doesn't even stop at that line...

Comment: *"There is no need to be hostile."*  ???  Don't post code at external links that go stale.  If you have an SSCCE, [edit it into the thread](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20321127/edit).

Comment: by the way, when you say "I compare it with zero" do you mean `isEmpty()` or something else?

Comment: @JulianUrbano, if you said that works fine for you, then I must be a local problem. I put a screenshot, anyway, showing how it does go to the return line.

Comment: It means `isEmpty()`, which is basically `.size() == 0`. If I change it, the problem remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question definitely falls to the "gray area" because from the code snippet you've provided it just can't happen - linked list definitely works and doesn't have a bug you can rely on it.
So the most obvious reason we can't really provide an answer is that we don't have enough information on this.

Now, You've said something 'interesting' or at least suspicious - when you remove a time measurement it works.
Sometimes this can happen when you're running multiple threads and one thread changes somehow the internal state of the list. 
For example: thread A get the reference to List that has 3 elements at time t1.
Thread B also has the same reference.
Thread B changes the state of the list at time t2 (t2 > t1), thread A has no idea about this it just keeps holding the reference and busy with its own work.
At time t3 (t3 > t2) Thread A access the list and obviously its already changed.

This is one possible reason to see such a behaviour.

Another direction to dig into :)

Have you tried to run this in a command line in an "old way" without IDE?
Sometimes (I admit very rarely and in remote debugging mostly) such a thing might happen because your sources are not in sync with what debugger thinks they are.
This might be solved by swiping out you compiled classes and rebuilding everything.
I know its unlikely to be the reason, but it worth mentioning.

Hope this helps somehow

Comment: Yep. I thought on that, but I'm not running more than one thread.
Oh, no.. I didn't. I will try that, thanks. :-)